# How to save the image in a resized QLabel?

Tags: c++, image, qt4, qlabel, pixmap

I have a QLabel that is loaded with a pixmap. I have it set so that when the window/QLlabel is resized, the image of the qlabel resizes as well.  However, when I try to save the image and retrieve the pixmap, it is the original loaded.  How would I go about retrieving the newly resized image from the QLabel and retrieving it as a QImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the resize event of your label, Use

```
Label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(YourImage).scaled(ui->Label->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));
```

For getting image as size of image use

```
Label->pixmap().toImage();
```

if this image is still not the same size as of label, Try

```
Label->pixmap().toImage().scaled(Label->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));
```

Comment: pixmap in label will be same. QLabel doesn't modify pixmap itself it only renders it scaled. Third way will work.